# Not able to automate list items from Treeview in desktop application using winium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, winium

I am stuck. I am trying to automate a desktop app using java (Winium), I am not able to automate controltype.pane as it show me automationid="" and name="" 
ever there is Classname and ControlType.  How does xpath or name or id is work here.

ClassName: "TreeView20WndClass"
    ControlType: "ControlType.Pane"
    Culture: "(null)"
    AutomationId: ""
    LocalizedControlType: "pane"
    Name: ""
    ProcessId:  "3456"
    RuntimeId:  "42 3868756"
    IsPassword: "False"
    IsControlElement:   "True"
    IsContentElement:   "True"

Help will be really appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find with a class name, you could use below code:

**driver.find_element_by_class_name('MySuperTextBox')**

where '**MySuperTextBox**' is class name in your case '**TreeView20WndClass**'.

For more details [click here](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki/Finding-Elements).